# ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have created a simple application using

```
rails new simple_cms -d mysql2
```

After running the WEBRick using command

```
   rails s
```

I created a controller and view

```
rails generate controller demo index
```

When I am pointing my browser to

```
  localhost:3000/demo/index
```

I am getting error

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
Rails.root: /Users/username/Sites/simple_cms
```

here is my gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.1'
gem 'mysql2', '0.3.11'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to create a MySQL database and configure the connection details in your `config/database.yml` file.

If the username and password in your `database.yml` file identify a user who has a global CREATE permission on your development database, then you can use the rake task

```
rake db:create
```

to get Rails to set up the database.

Comment: can I not create an application with db?

Comment: No, Rails needs to know a lot of things before it can connect to your db server to create a database, and it's made the decision that those aren't parameters relevant to creating the application from the command line.